# upgrading to desktop 18.04 from 16.04- could not get the desktop gnome or even unity displayed though even manually installed with no error message

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, 18.04, lightdm

Seems, I wasted a lot of time trying almost all suggestions including installing Lightdm - all i get is an empty purple color wall with active mouse cursor. 
- not even a seting icon
- barely managed to force a terminal (ctl+ alt +f2) to reinstall a bunch of packages that should have been installed during the upgrade process which went without any error message 
- was trying on an old hp g50 laptop with external screens

Any tested idea how to fix this?

Comment: Boot an 18.04 live usb and if it works do a fresh install, faster then debugging a failed upgrade. If it does not work, identify your hardware.

Comment: Tried clean install several times. No it does not make any difference .

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, its an old old laptiop hp g50126nr. with 2.16GHz pentium T3400 cpu with 3 GB ram, 256 GB drive - supposed to be plenty for this linux. Anyway, love to hear if anyone actually solved this anomaly....

Comment: Either use 16.04 or see https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it . Black, purple, different color same solution

Comment: of course 16.04 worked - no issue- my q was on upgrading to18.04. Anyway, once again, none of these worked for me.